# Error in metadata manager. An error occured when loading the read access database role

Tags: ssas, business-intelligence, olap-cube

> Full Process Dimensions :Error ,Error in metadata manager. An error occured when loading the read access database role, from the file, "\?\L:\OLAP\DATA(CubeName).0.db\Role.2.role.xml"

I fixed this error by redeploying from my backup solution and processing it again, but after 2 days this same error arise. Is there any permanent solution for this problem?

[image: error image]

Answer (score 0):

Most likely reason that Corruption in your XMLA File .

it is conflicting dimension definition between your cube structure or changes in the underlying source schema.

Best way would be Rebuild cube in BIDS, drop existing cube , re-deploy cube and process cube .

**NOTE**  Please do validation in DEV Environment before implementing at prod .

Comment: Thanks Sandeep
but last time i did the same things is there any another permanent solution then this?